# Changing df column that consists of list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame column "result" and it contains values (string list) like `["1","0"],["2","3"],["0","0"]` etc.,

What I want to do is changing the "result" column's values.For example, if the first element of the list is greater than the second, the value will be 1.If the second is greater, value will be 2 and if they are equal the value will be 0.

How can I efficiently do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[["1","0"],["2","3"],["0","0"]]})

def check(x):
    a, b = x
    a = int(a)
    b = int(b)
    if a == b:
        return 0
    elif a > b:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

df['new'] = [check(x) for x in df['col']]
print (df)
      col  new
0  [1, 0]    1
1  [2, 3]    2
2  [0, 0]    0
```

Another solution:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['col'].values.tolist(), columns=['a','b']).astype(int)
print (df1)
   a  b
0  1  0
1  2  3
2  0  0

masks = [df1.a > df1.b, df1.a < df1.b]
vals = [1,2]

df['new'] = np.select(masks, vals, default=0)
print (df)
      col  new
0  [1, 0]    1
1  [2, 3]    2
2  [0, 0]    0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use:

```
m=pd.DataFrame(df.a.values.tolist()).astype(int).add_prefix('val_')
df['new'] = np.select([m.val_0>m.val_1,m.val_0<m.val_1,m.val_0==m.val_1],[1,2,0])
print(df)

        a  new
0  [1, 0]    1
1  [2, 3]    2
2  [0, 0]    0
```

Comment: I think values are strings, so necessary convert them to integers.